# Determine the group of symmetries, giving a set of generators.

Tags: symmetric-groups, symmetry

> Determine the group of symmetries of the picture, giving a set of
>   generators.

Can you give me any hint please?

[image]

Comment: HInt: play with rotations and reflections and see what works.

Comment: I would say the rules of the game ought to be this:  to qualify as a symmetry, a transformation should be a symmetry of the whole square, which means in particular, it should be a bijective map of the whole square, take corners to corners, etc.  With these rules, you are looking for those symmetries of the square that don't mess up the decorations.

Comment: But it would be possible to play the game with a different set of rules, allowing a bigger group of symmetries. This could be the subject of a discussion with your class.

Comment: What I mean is that you could look at this figure as four decorated squares than just happen to have been placed together.  You could rotate the little squares separately and glue them back together.  That would be a different game with a different outcome.

Comment: @fredgoodman So the group of symmetries is $J = <A_{\frac{\pi}{2}}>$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is the rotation group of the square, of order 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP has now figured this out, I will post an answer.

Let $D = D_4$ be the group of symmetries of the square.

We are looking for the subgroup $G$ of $D$ that preserve the decorations.  By inspection, rotations  preserve the decorations, so $G$ contains the rotation subgroup $\mathcal R$. The subgroup $\mathcal R$ has index 2 in $D$, so either $G = \mathcal R$ or $G = D$.  Since, again by inspection, there is a reflection that does not preserve the decorations,  $G \ne D$.  Hence $G = \mathcal R$.

Comment: Thank you fredgoodman, can you help me with this other wallpaper please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641537/determining-the-group-of-symmetry

Comment: Ask me again in a week if you haven't figured it out.  Again the group $G$  is (by agreement) a subgroup of $D \cong D_4$.  You know the possible sizes of subgroups of $D$ are 1, 2, 4 and 8.  What size is your group?

Comment: I think the group is $G=\{I_2, A_{\pi}, F_v, F_h\}$ where $F_v$ is a vertical reflection and $F_h$ an horizontal reflection $(A_{\pi }\circ F_v = F_h)$ . This group has 4 elements so could be a subgroup of $D_4$ and be generetad by ${A_{\pi},F_v}$ then $G=<A_{\pi},F_v>$ ???

Comment: Hi, @fredgoodman, Can you help me with this new question about spherical trigonometry, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2688559/spherical-trigometry-for-sailing-problems